# Replace using *INI file in Docx - Python

Tags: python

My Python Code:

```
for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    # Replace placeholders with values from the INI file
    for key, value in replacements.items():
        if key in paragraph.text:
            paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace(key, value)
```

My *INI file:

`[replacements]`
`<inline>=` 
`</inline>=` 
`<display>=` 
`</display>=` 
`^p =` 
 `^p= ^p`
`^s=`

My request is to find the key and replace the corresponding values in the DOCX file using python code. I can able to replace like these `<inline>` words however I can't do this `^p`.

1. Space after end of the paragraph
2. Space at start of the paragraph
3. And similar replacements... etc..

Someone help on this one.

Comment: have you tried regex?

Comment: Not much knowledge in python coding